# Create a custom speech bubble tooltip that adapts/places its arrow/pointer to each situation

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, tooltip, .net-4.5

I have an WPF speech bubble tooltip which is working fine.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Canvas Width="225" Height="131">
                    <Path x:Name="Container"
                          Canvas.Left="0"
                          Canvas.Top="0"
                          Margin="0"
                          Data="M8,7.41 L15.415,0 L22.83,7.41 L224,7.41 L224,130 L0,130 L0,7.41 L8,7.41"
                          Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Stroke="Gray">
                        <Path.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                              Opacity="0.5"
                                              ShadowDepth="4" />
                        </Path.Effect>
                    </Path>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10"
                               Canvas.Top="10"
                               Width="100"
                               Height="65"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem with above approach is that the arrow/pointer of the speech bubble tooltip (path) is always placed in the same position regardless the situation and I would like it to adapt to the situation and use one of the following (above style implements the arrow placed at the top left, first tooltip in the screenshot below):

[image]

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi,@Rodri . Does the custom control in bazsisz's answer solve your problem? If not, could you describe the problem and provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, the full code for this task:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Decorators
{
public enum Position 
{
    None,
    Top,
    Bottom,
    RightSide,
    LeftSide,
}

public enum SpecificPosition
{
    None,
    LeftOrTop = 25,
    Center = 50,
    RightOrBottom = 75,
}

internal class BubbleTextDecorator : Decorator
{


    #region DependencyProperties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalMargin", 
                                                                                                   typeof(double), 
                                                                                                   typeof(BubbleTextDecorator), 
                                                                                                   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, 
                                                                                                                                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | 
                                                                                                                                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double VerticalMargin
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalMarginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalMarginProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HorizontalMargin", 
                                                                                                     typeof(double),
                                                                                                     typeof(BubbleTextDecorator),
                                                                                                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0,
                                                                                                                                   FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                                                                                                                                   FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double HorizontalMargin
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HorizontalMarginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalMarginProperty, value); }
    }



    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PointerPosition", 
                                                                                                    typeof(Position), 
                                                                                                    typeof(BubbleTextDecorator), 
                                                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Position.None, 
                                                                                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
                                                                                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public Position PointerPosition
    {
        get { return (Position)GetValue(PointerPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointerPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlignmentPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AlignmentPosition",
                                                                                            typeof(SpecificPosition),
                                                                                            typeof(BubbleTextDecorator),
                                                                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SpecificPosition.None,
                                                                                                                          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
                                                                                                                          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public SpecificPosition AlignmentPosition
    {
        get { return (SpecificPosition)GetValue(AlignmentPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlignmentPositionProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PointerHeight", 
                                                                                                  typeof(double), 
                                                                                                  typeof(BubbleTextDecorator), 
                                                                                                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, 
                                                                                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                                                                                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double PointerHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PointerHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointerHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PointerWidth", 
                                                                                                 typeof(double), 
                                                                                                 typeof(BubbleTextDecorator), 
                                                                                                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0,
                                                                                                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                                                                                                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |
                                                                                                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double PointerWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PointerWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointerWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Size desiredSize = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
        if (Child != null) 
        {

            switch (PointerPosition)
            {
                case Position.Top:
                    Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0.0, PointerHeight), new Point(desiredSize.Width, desiredSize.Height)));
                    break;
                case Position.Bottom:
                    Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0.0, 0.0), new Point(desiredSize.Width, desiredSize.Height - PointerHeight)));
                    break;
                case Position.LeftSide:
                    Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(PointerHeight, 0.0), new Point(desiredSize.Width, desiredSize.Height)));
                    break;
                case Position.RightSide:
                    Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0.0, 0.0), new Point(desiredSize.Width - PointerHeight, desiredSize.Height)));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size desiredSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        Size size = (PointerPosition == Position.Top || PointerPosition == Position.Bottom)
            ? new Size(desiredSize.Width + (HorizontalMargin * 2), desiredSize.Height + (VerticalMargin * 2) + PointerHeight)
            : new Size(desiredSize.Width + (HorizontalMargin * 2) + PointerHeight, desiredSize.Height + (VerticalMargin * 2));

        return size;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Brush renderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        Pen renderPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
        StreamGeometry geom = new StreamGeometry();

        switch (PointerPosition) 
        {
            case Position.Top:
                DrawTop(geom);
                break;
            case Position.Bottom:
                DrawBottom(geom);
                break;
            case Position.RightSide:
                DrawRight(geom);
                break;
            case Position.LeftSide:
                DrawLeft(geom);
                break;

        }
        // Some arbitrary drawing implements.
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(renderBrush, renderPen, geom);
    }

    private void DrawLeft(StreamGeometry geom)
    {
        using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geom.Open())
        {
            ctx.BeginFigure(
                new Point(PointerHeight, 0.0),
                true,
                true);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(PointerHeight, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(PointerHeight, (ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) + (PointerWidth / 2)),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(PointerHeight, (ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) - (PointerWidth / 2)),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(PointerHeight, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
        }
    }

    private void DrawRight(StreamGeometry geom)
    {
        using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geom.Open())
        {
            ctx.BeginFigure(
                new Point(0.0, 0.0),
                true,
                true);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth - PointerHeight, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth - PointerHeight, (ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) - (PointerWidth / 2)),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth - PointerHeight, (ActualHeight * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) + (PointerWidth / 2)),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth - PointerHeight, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
        }
    }

    private void DrawBottom(StreamGeometry geom)
    {
        using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geom.Open())
        {
            ctx.BeginFigure(
                new Point(0.0, 0.0),
                true,
                true);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
               new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight - PointerHeight),
               true,
               false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point((ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) + (PointerWidth / 2), ActualHeight - PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point((ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) - (PointerWidth / 2), ActualHeight - PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, ActualHeight - PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
        }
    }

    private void DrawTop(StreamGeometry geom)
    {
        using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geom.Open())
        {
            ctx.BeginFigure(
                new Point(0.0, PointerHeight),
                true,
                true);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point((ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) - (PointerWidth / 2), PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100, 0.0),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point((ActualWidth * (double)AlignmentPosition / 100) + (PointerWidth / 2), PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(ActualWidth, PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
               new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight),
               true,
               false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, ActualHeight),
                true,
                false);
            ctx.LineTo(
                new Point(0.0, PointerHeight),
                true,
                false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
<localdecorators:BubbleTextDecorator PointerHeight="10"
                                    PointerWidth="20"
                                    PointerPosition="LeftSide"
                                    AlignmentPosition="Center"
                                    VerticalMargin="30"
                                    HorizontalMargin="30"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<TextBlock Text="this"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</localdecorators:BubbleTextDecorator>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I like the idea, the problem with this approach is that you need to tell it explicitly in what position the arrow/pointer should be drawn but this is a thing that it is decided and calculated automatically by OS i guess which it know if there is enough space in the screen and based on this it decides where to draw it.

Comment: @Willy I will try to find the solution for you, if i have spare time. I think with this approch is not a lot more work to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is a typical case for creating a Decorator. I once made a customizable ArrowBorder around a Text. You need to inherit from the Decorator class.

```
internal class ArrowBorderDecorator : Decorator
```

Then you need some DependencyProperties so that it will be easy to customize.
In my case that was the `ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistance` property which means how "pointy" the arrow should be.In your case where should the bubble text arrows should be.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistanceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistance", typeof(double), typeof(ArrowBorderDecorator), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistance
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistanceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistanceProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then you need to override the `ArrangeOverride`, `MeasureOverride` and the `OnRender` methods. The first two comes from the Decorator class and the third is from the UIElement class.

Here is a nice [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818340/measureoverride-and-arrangeoverride-what-is-really-availablesize-desiredsize) to understand the first two.
In `OnRender` you have a DrawingContext to draw your desired shape using the DependenyProperties.

After these you can simply use your decorator in your xaml like this:

```
<localdecorators:ArrowBorderDecorator ArrowBaseHalfSegment="0"
             FillColor="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent3}"
             StrokeColor="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeForeground}"
             ArrowBorderThickness="1"
             ArrowTipToArrowTriangleBaseDistance="10">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
           Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"
           Padding="10 1 10 1"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontWeight="Bold">
</TextBlock></localdecorators:ArrowBorderDecorator>
```

[image: Result]
[image: Result2]